# How do I set dropzone to upload if only a minimum of 10 files are on the qeue?

Tags: limit, dropzone.js, minimum

How do I set dropzone to upload if only a minimum of 10 files are on the qeue?

I have set the autoProcessQueue to false, so that when the submit button is clicked a fucntion will run to check the qeued files. If they are less or greater than 10 the upload won't take place.

How do I achive this?
Please assist.

I have searched everywhere on google but I cannot seem to find the answer. . Please assist!

Here is my code..

```
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<link href="css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
<form role= "form"></form>
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
</body>

<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

// Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
autoProcessQueue: false,

init: function() {
var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
myDropzone = this; // closure

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.



});

myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) { this.removeFile(file); });


// You might want to show the submit button only when 
// files are dropped here:
this.on("addedfile", function() {
// Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
});

}
};
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this inside the init function using the method `getQueuedFiles()` from dropzone:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function () {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
        myDropzone = this;
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length >= 10) { 
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            }
            else {
                alert("Not enough files!");
            }
        });
    }
};

var myDropzone = new Dropzone('form#my-dropzone');
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Just exactly what I was looking for!